# How fast does USB 3.0 perform?

Tags: performance, usb-3

How fast does USB 3.0 actually perform? I remember from quite a bit of experience that USB 2.0, while fast on paper, never in any practical situation hit those speeds in reality (the "slower" FireWire 400 always ran circles around USB 2.0, even on the same hard drive).

So what I want to know is how much of USB 3.0's theoretical speeds are actually reached?

Comment: have you tried googling your question?

Comment: This can be answered by the USB 3.0 specification website or the wiki article on USB 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [link](http://www.everythingusb.com/speed.html) with some actual read write speeds.  You are correct, the speeds on the white sheet will never be the same as you get on your local PC.  There are several reasons for this.  Who made the NAND/Flash inside the USB 3.0 Device? Brand matters, some MFG's sell varying levels of memory and you often get what you pay for.  Buy a decent device and you will be happy, read the forums and reviews of the device you plan on buying and make sure the reported actual speeds are what your are willing to live with.